# What is a request code while using finishActivity()

Tags: java, android

In a game I've been making I would like the player to go back to the main menu once they lose:

```
if (gameOver) {
   Intent i = new Intent(this.context, MainActivity.class);
   this.context.startActivity(i);
}
```

The code above works, but once I try to rerun the game, everything crashes.

I think `finishActivity` might work, but I'm not sure what a request code is.

Comment: A request code helps you identify an intent, that's all it does. Set it to a unique positive value and avoid setting the request code of other intents to that same value.

Answer (score 1):

The request code that you input in `finishActivity()` is the same request code that you get at `onActivityResult()`.

This is only valid when you launch an activity using `startActivityForResult()`. This means that it doesn't matter in your case because you're using `startActivity()`.

Use `finish()` instead.